# Make a li link work

Tags: html, css

I'm very new to programming and I made a menu for my website, it has a dropdown function but now when I click 1 of the links in the dropdown it doesn't do anything but disapear. I have been trying for days now but I can't seem to be able to fix it. Can someone help?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Travellikewedo | Travelguide</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="indeximg/favicon.ico">
</head>
        <body>

        <!-- Navigation -->

<header>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <nav>
            <a href="index.html"><h1 class="logo">travellikewedologo</h1></a>
            <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/kellyjohantravel" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>

        <a class="burger-nav"></a>
            <h2>Main Navigation</h2>
        <ul>

        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a href="#">Reizen +</a>
          <div class="dropdown-container">
            <div class="dropdown-inner">
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">Landen</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">Meenemen</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">Tips</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a href="#">Blog +</a>
          <div class="dropdown-container">
            <div class="dropdown-inner">
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="dropdown-menu-item"><a href="/blog/2016.html">2016</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>  


            <li><a href="/overons.html">Over ons</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>

        <!-- Content -->


    <div id="index-banner">
        <img src="indeximg/banner.jpg" alt="welkom" class="banner-image">
    </div>

 <div id="indexcontent">

    <div class="sideright">
        <h2>Advertenties</h2>
        <p>tekst met een W zodat we kunnen zien of Raleway werkt</p>
        <p>tekst</p>
        <p>tekst</p>
        <p>tekst</p>
    </div>

    <div class="main">
        <h1>Nieuw</h1>
        <p>blabla</p>
    </div>

    <div> 
        <img class="imagesidebar" src="indeximg/banner.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="main">
        <h1>Nieuw</h1>
        <p>blabla</p>
    </div>

    <div class="sideright">
        <h2>Advertenties</h2>
        <p>tekst</p>
        <p>tekst</p>
        <p>tekst</p>
        <p>tekst</p>
    </div>

    <div class="main">
        <h1>Nieuw</h1>
        <p>blabla</p>
     </div>

    <div id="footer">
       <div id="social"> 

           <div class="socialthumb"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/kellyjohantravel/"> <img class="socialthumbimg" src="social/facebookicon.svg"></a>
            </div>

           <div class="socialthumb"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/travel_like_we_do/"><img class="socialthumbimg" src="social/instagramicon.svg"></a>
            </div>

           <div class="socialthumb"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCLQ3Vq79f6CjnlOy1tjT9GQ"><img class="socialthumbimg" src="social/youtubeicon.svg"></a>
            </div>

       </div>
        <p>&copy TraveLlikewedo.com 2016</p>
     </div>

</div>

    </body>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="menu.js"></script>
</html>

@font-face{ 
    font-family: 'raleway';
    src: url('fonts/raleway.eot');
    src: url('fonts/raleway.eot?iefix') format('eot'),
         url('fonts/raleway.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/raleway.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/raleway.svg#webfont') format('svg');
}


body {
  font-family: "raleway", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #4c4c4c;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

p{
    color: #999;
}

/* ===== Navigation ===== */

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1180px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.fb_iframe_widget {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

h1.logo {
  background-image: url(indeximg/logo602.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 135px;
  height: 50px;
  text-indent: -10000px;
  float: left;
  margin: 15px;
}

header nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  float: right;
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #bcbcbc;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
}

header nav h2 {
  text-indent: -10000px;
  height: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header nav li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 10px 20px;
}

header nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4c4c4c;
  font-size: 1em;
}

header nav ul {
  float: right;
  margin: 19.5px 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header nav li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.dropdown a:focus {
  color: #bcbcbc;
}

.dropdown a:focus ~ .dropdown-container {
  max-height: 500px;
  transition:max-height 0.5s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition:max-height 0.5s ease-in;
  -moz-transition:max-height 0.5s ease-in;
}

.dropdown-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 83px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fff;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.dropdown-menu li a {
  padding: 10px; 
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-menu-item{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

/* ===== Index banner ===== */

.banner-image {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  top: 80px;
}

/* ===== Content ===== */

#indexcontent{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px 0;
    top: 600px;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #eee;
}

.main{
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 320px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #e5e3e3;
}

.sideright{
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #e5e3e3;
    float: right;
    width: 260px;
    clear: right;
}
.imagesidebar{
    margin: 10px;
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
    clear: right;
}

/* ===== Reizen banner ===== */

.reizenbanner-image {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 220px;
  top: 80px;
}

h1.bannertext{
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 400%;
    border: solid 3px #fff;
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin: 90px 0 0 15px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #bcbcbc;
}

/* ===== Subpage Content ===== */

#subpage-content{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    top: 302px;
    background-color: #eee;
}

.subpage-main{
    margin: 1%;
    padding: 2%;
    width: 44%;
    float: left;
}

.subpage-sideright{
    margin: 1%;
    padding: 2%;
    width: 44%;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}
.subpage-imagesidebar {
    margin: 3%;
    width: 44%;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.personal-info {
    margin: 1%;
    padding: 2%;
    width: 64%;
    float: left;
}

.personal-image {
    margin-top: 6%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 3%;
    width: 27%;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 50px solid #fff;
}

/* ===== Contact =====*/

.contact-banner-image {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 220px;
  top: 83px;
}

#contact-content{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px 0;
    top: 303px;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #eee;
}

#contact {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 250px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.form-control {
    font-family: "raleway";
    font-size: 1.1em;
    height: 25px;
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #bcbcbc;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#message.form-control {
    height: 70px;
}

/* ===== Footer ===== */

#footer{
    padding-top: 30px;
    background-color: #eee;
    height: 150px;
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
}

#social{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
}

.socialthumbimg{
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
}

.socialthumb{
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    margin: 10px 5%;
    display: inline-block;
}


/* ===== mobiles and tablets =====*/

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

/* ===== Navigation ===== */

 .fb_iframe_widget {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 20px 0;
  }

  h1.logo{
    margin: 5px;
  }

  header nav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
  }

  .burger-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 20px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    background: url(indeximg/hamburger.png) no-repeat 85% center;
    float: right;
  }

  header nav ul {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #fff;
    height: 0;
  }

  header nav ul.open {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }

  header nav ul li {
    float: none;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }

  header nav ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bcbcbc;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-container {
    position: static;
      }

.dropdown-menu li a {
    display: block;
    text-indent: 20px;
}


/* ===== Banner ===== */

  #index-banner img {
    position: fixed;
    width: 200%;
    height: 600px;
    left: -50%;
    top: 60px;
  }

/* ===== Content ===== */

.main{
    margin: 1%;
    padding: 2%;
    width: 94%;
    background-color: #e5e3e3;
    float: left;
}

.sideright{
    margin: 1%;
    padding: 2%;
    width: 94%;
    background-color: #e5e3e3;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}
.imagesidebar{
    margin: 1%;
    width: 98%;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}  

/* ===== Reizen banner ===== */

.reizenbanner-image {
  position: fixed;
  width: 200%;
  height: 220px;
  left: -50%;
  top: 60px;
}

/* ===== Subpage Content ===== */

#subpage-content{
    top: 283px;
}

.subpage-main{
    width: 94%;
}

.subpage-sideright{
    width: 94%;
}

.subpage-imagesidebar {
    width: 94%;
}

.personal-info {
    width: 94%;
}

.personal-image {
    margin: 3%;
    width: 94%;
}

/* ===== Contact ===== */

.form-control {
    width: 80%;
}
#message.form-control {
    width: 80%;
}
.contact-banner-image {
    top: 63px;
}   
#contact-content{
    top: 280px;
} 

}






$(document).ready(function(){

      $(".burger-nav").on("click", function(){

        $("header nav ul").toggleClass("open"); 

      });
});


(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/nl_NL/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Comment: Which links are you looking at? The Landen, Meenemen and Tips ones I would expect to do nothing. You're not mistakenly doing your checks with those are you? the 2016, Over ons and Contact links I would expect to navigate to the urls given. This assumes no script on the page making them do something else.

Comment: I am checking with the 2016 button wich does nothing. Over ons and contact are both working fine, but they are not in the drop down. So i think it has something to do with the styling of dropdown-menu-item li tags. But i cant figure out what it is.

Comment: Do you have any script intercepting click events? If the other two are working and 2016 isn't it seems the most likely explanation is that there is a click event bound to something like dropdown-menu-item that is supressing the default click behaviour.

Comment: I have a little javascript running for clicking a hamburger menu in and out. I have put my whole site in the question area. If the javascript is interfering with the click event, is there something i can do to force the click event?

Comment: http://codepen.io/lordruler/pen/mPNvjm here you can see it is not working. I have changed the link for 2016 to the full lunk so it should redirect even trough codepen. but not working.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is that when you click on a menu item the focus is lost and the menu disappears before the link could be activated.

you can see that if the menu stays open the link works by removing the `:focus` like this:

```
.dropdown a ~ .dropdown-container {
  max-height: 500px;
  transition:max-height 0.5s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition:max-height 0.5s ease-in;
  -moz-transition:max-height 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

try adding an animation for when the focus is lost,

or maybe find a better solution then `.dropdown a:focus ~ .dropdown-container {`

here is an example:
HTML:
 
            travellikewedologo

```
    <a class="burger-nav"></a>
        <h2>Main Navigation</h2>
    <ul>

    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a href="#">Reizen +</a>
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <div class="dropdown-inner">
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">Landen</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">Meenemen</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown-menu-item"><a href="#">Tips</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a href="#">Blog +</a>
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <div class="dropdown-inner">
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="dropdown-menu-item"><a href="/blog/2016.html">2016</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>  


        <li><a href="/overons.html">Over ons</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
```

notice a added `<nav class="nav">`

css:

```
.nav li ul {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:36px;
    z-index:1;
}
.nav li ul li {
    overflow:hidden;
    height:0;
    -webkit-transition:height 200ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition:height 200ms ease-in;
    -o-transition:height 200ms ease-in;
    transition:height 200ms ease-in;
}
.nav ul > li:hover ul li {
    height:36px;
}
```

merge this with your corrent css

Comment: Tnx! I can see that it works if i remove the focus. But i dont think that i know how to add an animation. Do you know a simple way to get the menu to slide in and out but keep the functionality of the link?

Comment: take a look a this page : http://www.newmediacampaigns.com/blog/nicer-navigation-with-css-transitions-part-2

Comment: I have looked at the code there and fiddled around for over an hour but still can't find a solution to the problem.

Comment: Updated my answer for you